# Layered rendering cubemap in one pass

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3, geometry-shader

I am trying to make a dynamic cubemap with geometry shader and gl_Layer where each face have is own texture but it doesn't work like expected. Or I have a black cubemap with nothing or  I have nothing...

this is where I initialize my texture and fbo :

```
void init(void) {
    //Triangle test
    GLfloat data[] = {
            0, 0, 0,
            1, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vaoTriangles);
    glBindVertexArray(_vaoTriangles);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vboPoints);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboTriangles);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const void *)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER ,0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    const GLfloat skybox[] = {
            // positions
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skybox), skybox, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const void *)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER ,0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture_cubemap);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture_cubemap);
    int face;
    for(face = 0; face < 6; face++)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+face, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(1, _fbo);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture_cubemap, 0);

//    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthFbo);
//    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthFbo);
//    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 256, 256);
//    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthFbo);

//    GLenum drawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
//    glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Here the render :

```
void render(void) {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);
    glViewport(0, 0, 256, 256);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0);
    glUseProgram(pIdTriangles);
    glBindVertexArray(_vaoTriangles);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    glUseProgram(pId);
//...Matrices stuff
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);
    gl4duSendMatrices();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture_cubemap);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(pId, "skybox"), 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);
```

My shaders for the skybox:

```
//Vertex shader
#version 330


layout(location=0) in vec3 positionSkybox;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
out vec3 UV;

void main() {
    vec4 pos = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix /* modelMatrix */* vec4(positionSkybox, 1);
    gl_Position = pos.xyww;
    UV = positionSkybox;
}

//Fragment shader
#version 330

//layout(location=0) in vec4 outColor;

out vec4 fragColor;
uniform samplerCube skybox;
in vec3 UV;

void main() {
    fragColor = texture(skybox, UV);
}
```

And shaders for the model :

```
//Vertex shader
#version 330

layout(location=0) in vec3 positionTriangles;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

void main() {
    gl_Position = /*projectionMatrix */ /*viewMatrix */ modelMatrix * vec4(positionTriangles, 1);
}

//Geometry shader
#version 330

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=18) out;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

out vec4 colors;
void main() {
    int i, layer;
    for(layer = 0; layer < 6; ++layer){
        gl_Layer = layer;
        for(i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++){
            gl_Position = /*projectionMatrix */ gl_in[0].gl_Position;
            colors = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
            EmitVertex();
        }
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}

//Fragment shader 
#version 330

out vec4 fragColor;

in vec4 colors;
void main() {
    fragColor = colors;//vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Thanks for the help ...

EDIT : 
My skybox works only if :

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, **0**);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, 256, 256);
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0);
    glUseProgram(pIdTriangles);
    glBindVertexArray(_vaoTriangles);
//Draw the triangles

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, **_fbo**);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    glUseProgram(pId);
//Draw the skybox
```

But it's the skybow that must render on the default framebuffer, am I right ?

Comment: Sorry It was pIdTriangles ... pIdTriangles is the pId where I draw my triangles and have the vertex, geometry, and fragment shaders. And pId is the skybox.

Answer (score 2):

You have to complete a primitive per layer, move [`EndPrimitive()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/EndPrimitive.xhtml) in the loop which iterates the layers.

Further, in your code the 1st vertex of the triangle is used three times, but the 2nd and 3rd coordinate are missed. 
Change `gl_in[0].gl_Position` to `gl_in[i].gl_Position`.

To render the different sides of the cubemap you'll need a different view matrix for each side of the cubemap. You have to "look" in each direction (right, left, front, back, up and down).
The projection matrix has to be a perspective projection, with a filed of view angle of 90 degrees and an aspect ratio of 1.0:
See also the tutorial ["OpenGL: One-pass rendering to a cube map"](http://cg.siomax.ru/index.php/computer-graphics/10-one-pass-rendering-to-cube-map), for more a detailed information.

e.g. by usnig [glm::lookAt](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00668.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e) and [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00665.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787)

```cpp
glm::mat4 cubeView[6] =
{ 
    glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f)), // +X
    glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f)), // -X
    glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)), // +Y
    glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f)), // -Y
    glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f)), // +Z
    glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f)), // -Z
};

glm::mat4 cubeProj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.0f), 1.0f, near_plane, far_plane);
```

```c
uniform mat4 cubeProjMatrix;
uniform mat4 cubeViewMatrix[6];

void main() {
    int i, layer;
    for(layer = 0; layer < 6; ++layer){
        gl_Layer = layer;
        for(i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
        {
            gl_Position = cubeProjMatrix * cubeViewMatrix[layer] * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
            colors = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
            EmitVertex();
        }
        EndPrimitive(); // <---- insert 
    }
    //EndPrimitive();   // <---- delete
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I did what you say but nothing changed. My screen is full grey from the glClearColor in the framebuffer and that's all...

Comment: EDIT : I had GL_DEPTH_TEST and GL_CULL_FACE enable but when I commented I obtained a black cube ... Why ... ?

Comment: Ok, but nothing changed too, and in a desperate act, I switched the fbo id (bind fbo for the skybox and 0 for triange) and I obtained the green from the geometry shader but without triangles.

Comment: I have a triangle but only if I set him a view and model matrices. And It's not on each face of the cube ... I think I did something weird.
EDIT  : do I have to leave the bindFramebuffer to bind to the fbo for the skybox et the models to 0 ? If not I still get a black cube... I really don't understand why

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it ... But last question, The skybox I have to bind it to 0 in the framebuffer, right ? Because the few tutorials I saw it's on 0 and in my case if I bind it to 0 I have only a black cube...

Comment: I'm sorry, it was not what I meant. I meant : for the skybox I have to do : `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);` and for the triangles : `    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);` it's not supposed to be reversed ? If yes, why in my case it's like this that it work ?

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it's not supposed to be the skybox that we render to the default frame buffer instead the objects that we draw on each face ?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english x), please see my edit I hope you will understand what I am saying

Comment: @Bomu Do you use a perspective projection in the geometry shader? Slight change the z coordinates of the triangle, so that it is not clipped by the near plane of the perspective projection.

Comment: Yes, i tried it but i have nothing... I know that I messed up somewhere but I don't know I'm going to cry x)